# React.js doesn't display fetched image from Django

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, django-models

My component successfully fetches info (texts and images) from the Django backend but fails to display the images.

related: [react.js doesn't display fetched image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72529614/react-js-doesnt-display-fetched-image?noredirect=1#comment128129152_72529614)

I removed file 192png from manifest.js and HTML and it didn't work so I put them back again as advised.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Fragment} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Carousel from 'react-elastic-carousel';
import './Schools.css';
import Test from '../assets/images/back.jpg';

const schoolBreakPoints = [
    {width: 1, itemsToShow: 1 },
    {width: 550, itemsToShow: 2 },
    {width: 768, itemsToShow: 3 },
    {width: 1200, itemsToShow: 4 },
];

function Schools() {
    const [languageCenters, setLanguageCenters] = useState ([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        };

        const getLanguageCenters = async () => {
            try {
                const res = await axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/api/partners/list/`, config);
                setLanguageCenters(res.data);
            }
            catch (err) {

            }
        };

        getLanguageCenters();
    }, []);

    const getAllLanguageCenters = () => {
        let allLanguageCenters = [];
        let results = [];

        languageCenters.map(languageCenter => {
            console.log(languageCenter.photo)
            return allLanguageCenters.push(
                <Fragment key={languageCenter.id}>
                    <div className='school__display'>
                        <img className='school__display__image' src={languageCenter.photo} alt='school logo' />
                    </div>
                    <h3 className='school__language__center'>{languageCenter.name}</h3>
                    <p className='school__course'>{languageCenter.country}</p>
                    <p className='school__course'>{languageCenter.language}</p>
                    <p className='school__course'>{languageCenter.course}</p>
                    <p className='school__about'>{languageCenter.note}</p>
                </Fragment>
            );
        });

        for (let i = 0; i < languageCenters.length; i += 20) {
            results.push(
                <div key={i} className='school__card__row'>
                    <Carousel breakPoints={schoolBreakPoints}>
                        <div className='school__card'>
                            {allLanguageCenters[i]}
                        </div>
                        <div className='school__card'>
                            {allLanguageCenters[i+1] ? allLanguageCenters[i+1] : null}
                        </div>
                        <div className='school__card'>
                            {allLanguageCenters[i+2] ? allLanguageCenters[i+2] : null}
                        </div>
                        <div className='school__card'>
                            {allLanguageCenters[i+3] ? allLanguageCenters[i+3] : null}
                        </div>
                        <div className='school__card'>
                            {allLanguageCenters[i+4] ? allLanguageCenters[i+4] : null}
                        </div>
                    </Carousel>
                </div>
            );
        }

        return results;
    };  

  return (
    <div className='schools'>
        <section className='schools__language__centers'>
            <div className='schools__row'>
                <h2 className='schools__subheading'>Language Centers</h2>
            </div>
            {getAllLanguageCenters()}
        </section>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Schools
```

developer tool > all ;

[image: developer tool > all]

developer tool > img ;

[image: developer tool > img]

And below is what I see on the browser, only the broken icon and the rel ;

[image: on browser]

Comment: Do you need to prepend a different base URL to the `languageCenter.photo` path so the code fetches from the correct server and location? Where are these images located?

Comment: Hi Drew, I'm not sure if I understood the question, I don't think that I need a different base URL. These images are located on my local machine in the Django project server. I tested the URL  on postman and I got an object with texts and photos without problems.

Comment: Right, fetching the data doesn't appear to be the issue. It's the image source URL being used later when getting the images, the images *aren't* where the app is "looking" for them. In the public folder is there a `"/public/media/partners/2022/06/07"` directory?

Comment: Hi Drew, Many thanks. The images are not in the public folder or react folders but in a folder inside the Django project. Actually, I managed to find a walk-around, when I use the build folder in Django through Django-server, the images are appearing perfectly. It's annoying why to react can't display them.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a walk-around, when I use the build folder in Django through Django-server, the images are appearing perfectly. It's ok for me because I'm building a Django project but it's annoying why React can't display them.